# Get the lowest possible pylint score within 128 bytes of python

Tags: code-challenge, python, hello-world, error-message

[pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) has no lower bound on the scores it will give your code. It uses the following metric to score code, with the maximum score being 10:

```
10.0 - ((float(5 * error + warning + refactor + convention) / statement) * 10)
```

With python 3.6, try and write a program that:

- Outputs "Hello World" when run from the command line (i.e. `python script.py`), and no other output.
- Gets the lowest possible score from `pylint`, with default settings (i.e. `pylint script.py`)
- Is strictly less than or equal to 128 bytes in size.

Comment: I suggest to change the title to `Python 3.6` instead of `python` to improve challenge scope clarity.

Answer (score 17):

## -5430

```python
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++exit("Hello World")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOITk/JVWvoJKrPFlBNxnOK6gsycjPM4bxFZQVCooy80qKFUryFYJDXFyDgoBKcoAiMBX//2vTE6RWZJZoKHmk5uTkK4TnF@WkKGkCAA)

Answer (score 5):

## <s>-3330.00</s> -3540.00

- Lost 210 points thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) -- exiting with the required string instead of printing it.

```python
exit("Hello World"
)>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_>_,_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDySM1JydfITy/KCdFiUvTLl4nnl74/38A)

Comment: -3330 is the score with a trailing newline, which puts the byte count at 129. The missing final newline decreases the score to -3340.

Comment: [-3540](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOITk/JVWvoJKrPFlBNxnOK6gsycjPM4bxFZQVCooy80qKFUryFYJDXFyDgoBKcoAiMBX//6dWZJZoKHmk5uTkK4TnF@WkKHFp2sXrxNMLAwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennis Did not know pylint penalizes you for the trailing new line; thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 2):

## -840.0

```python
print("Hello World"),0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0,0<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8kjNScnXyE8vygnRUlTx8DGgF74/38A)

`0<0` seems to be pretty good, for a score of -30 points per each occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

## -335.0

126 bytes

```
print("Hello World");import os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os,os
```

Comment: Could you not squeeze another `,os` in there? Or are the two trailing spaces necessary for your score?